# How to calculate normal force acting on part attached with a screw? Can the force on screws be decreased by lowering the height of the normal force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

I have an L-shaped beam (equal height and width lengths) hanging from a screw on the wall, and I model the screw as a pin joint (hopefully okay approximation even though it does apply a constant force on the beam). I'm trying to figure out how well secured the screws need to be to the wall. Diagram below.

```
      A (pin joint)
      o --> Ax
      |
      | <-- N
      | h
._____. B
:
v
F
```

Then if the rest of the vertical part of the beam is touching the wall, where approximately, in terms of height, could I model a point normal force applying? In reality the normal force applies along the entire height of the part touching the wall, but varies with height (and the amount of force applied by the screw). Specifically, I am interested in the case where a downward force is applied at the far end of the L beam. Intuitively, I feel the normal force will be applied closer to B the higher F is. But I am not sure how to start solving this.

**For example:**

The forces acting on my part are Ax, Ay, N, and F. The dimensions of the vertical and horizontal components of the part are 1m for simplicity and I want to solve in terms of F. The unknowns are Ax, Ay, N, and h, but solving for Ay is trivial I think.

Using sum of x forces gives: `Ax - N = 0 --> Ax=N`. Therefore, we have that the normal force will be equal to the force pulling the screws out of the wall. Is that right?

Then additional equations includes moments about B: `F - Ax + h*N = 0` which simplifies to `F + (h-1)*N=0`

And sum of moments about A: `F - (1-h)*N = 0` which simplifies to `F + (h-1)*N = 0`.

This is the same as sum of moments about B, and that makes sense since it's all the same part, unfortunately. The sum of moments about the point where F is applied also simplifies to the same equation after substituting `Ay=F`.

Therefore, I don't have enough equations to solve this problem and don't know how to proceed here. How do I find another equation to give me h? Or is there a different approach to modeling this problem? Finding h could be an integration problem if I know the equation form of load applied to the wall, but I don't know how to get started finding that equation form - linear from 0 at A to F at B? (if so, why?)

Lastly, I have that `Ax = F / (1-h)` where h is inversely related to how far from A the normal force is. This should mean that the lower on the wall I get the normal force, the less force is applied to the screws, right? Like would a T design for a wall bracket (diagram below) reduce the force pulling out the screws? It kind of makes intuitive sense, but again, I would like to be able to calculate it to make sure.

```
    o-->Ax
    |
----|
:   |<--N
v   |
F
```

Comment: Also note that you can slide the force $F$ up and down and it will not change the problem, which means the T-design is mathematically equivalent to the L-design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most general case, of a T-design, I think you are looking at something like this

[image: fig1]

Where $F$ is the applied force, and $B_x$, $A_y$, and $A_x$ represent the forces provided by the screws to keep the bracket stable.

As you will see, moving the shelf up and down (changing the $d$ value) does not affect the forces on the screws.

The standard way to proceed is to form the three equilibrium equations and solve for the 3 unknown forces.

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} A_x + B_x & = 0 \\ A_y - F & = 0 \\ h B_x +\ell F & = 0 \end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned} A_x & = \tfrac{\ell}{h} F \\ A_y & = F \\ B_x & = \mbox{-}\tfrac{\ell}{h} F \end{aligned} $$

And there you have it. Calculate $A_x$ to get the required screw tension to keep the shelf in place. If you *know* what the screw tension  $A_x$ is, then you can back solve for the minimum $h$ value

$$ \boxed{ h \ge \frac{F}{A_x} \ell }$$

---

For completion, you could also slide all the forces to find where they meet

[image: fig2]

and solving the for the force balance only, with no need to take moments. Notice that the direction $\theta$ of the net force at the top screw is fixed by the geometry as $\tan \theta = \tfrac{\ell}{h}$. Then the force balance equations are

$$ \left. \begin{aligned} A \sin \theta + B & = 0 \\ A \cos \theta - F & = 0  \end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned} A & = \frac{F}{\cos \theta} \\ B & = \mbox{-} F \tan \theta \end{aligned} $$

And the pull-out force of the top screww $$A_x = A \sin \theta = (\tan \theta ) F$$

So again, if you know the screw tension $A_x$, solve for the minimum design angle

$$ \boxed{ \tan \theta \ge \frac{A_x}{F} }$$

Comment: Cool thanks! This is confirming my design analysis that a T bracket can decrease the Ax forces. But I am still confused about why the normal force should apply entirely at B. Since all the forces are external, it only makes sense that B is the normal force exerted by the wall right? So normal force only applying all the way at the bottom of the part is probably an approximation? For example, if you had a negligible F+weight and the screw at A applied high forces on the part, then normal force would be much higher at A than B.

Comment: The T-design is no different than the L-design in terms of forces. Nowhere in the equations is the distance $d$ appears, and its value does not effect the results.

Comment: Absolutely it is different. A greater h decreases the x component of A. (h from your example not mine.)

Comment: @SvenVoigt - are you asking why there is no vertical force at **B**? The reason is that both **B** and **A** share the vertical force, and placing it all in **A** is the more conservative option resulting in the highest possible forces at **A**. This means that if you can design with these assumptions, you are going to be safe(er) in real life.

Comment: @SvenVoigt an L-design still has an $h$ value. What differentiates the two, is $d=0$ for the L-design, and $d>0$ for the T-design.

Comment: True. I was talking about my L design vs my T design. But yes I understand that you're saying the L vs T shape doesn't matter as long as you get the B force lower (increase h).

Comment: And no, I am asking why is the horizontal force applied only at B?

Comment: External forces include normal force no?

Comment: @SvenVoigt - Please define normal force. In mechanics, normal forces refrer to forces normal (perpendicular) to a surface; hence, horizontal forces are normal on the wall. I think you are referring to the _shear_ forces on the screws, which are the vertical forces along the wall. See my comment above of why **B** does not carry any shear load.

Comment: No the contact area between the part experiences a force along the entire length of the part. It is a "distributed load". Why should that distributed load only apply at B? I am assuming your Ax force is the tensile force exerted by the screws and B is some point force that is equivalent to the integration of the distributed load representing the force between two surfaces in contact.

Comment: Note that when you have a flat-on-flat contact, the "distributed" load goes to the edges only. This is a feature of contact mechanics. Only when considering the flexibility of the bracket can you gain more insight into the distribution of forces, and there you need some FEA software to do so.

Comment: Do you have some more background on why it only goes to the edges? I am assuming that is only the case if the external environment (wall in this case) needs to have a torque counteracting the one on the part, resulting in the need for a couple (one positive force in direction of some vector, v normal to the contact surface, and one negative force in direction of v). In other cases, such as a clamp acting on some part with a clamping force, wouldn't there be uniformly distributed load and an equivalent point force at the center of the contact surface?

Comment: If you read on contact mechanics you will run across the phenomenon of "edge-stress" on contacting surfaces. For example the third column of [Table 11-1](https://engineeringlibrary.org/reference/bearing-stress-air-force-stress-manual) gives you contact pressure, and for the last two geometries, this is infinite at the edge. Like in impulse, the integral of pressure over area gives a _finite_ force even though the pressure is infinite, and this force is concentrated at the edge.

Comment: Also [Figure 2a -  Effect of Contact Geometry on the Contact Stresses in a Flat with Round Edge Contact](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332628523_Effect_of_Contact_Geometry_on_the_Contact_Stresses_in_a_Flat_with_Round_Edge_Contact) shows this effect also, where the distributed load is mostly at the edges.